# Webpack dev server - run multiple apps on multiple ports

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Currently I run two apps that sits on the same repo.

The first one runs on `/` and the other one on `port 3000` (different HTML files).

I want to make another app that will run on `port 5000` (with it's own HTML file).

How can I do that?

This is my Webpack config:

```
   entry: {

       mainApp: "./MainApp.js",
       appNumberTwo: "./AppNumberTwo.js"
   }, 

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    historyApiFallback: {
        index: publicPath + 'app_number_2.html',
    },
    proxy: [{
        target: "http://www.dev.mydomain.com"
    }]
},
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. You can try using multiple compilers like this,

```
//webpack.config.js
[{
    entry: "./entry1.js",
    output: {
        filename: "outpu1.js"
    }
}, {
    entry: "./entry2.js",
    output: {
        filename: "outpu2.js"
    }
}]
```

then create a node script like this,

```
const WebpackDevServer = require("webpack-dev-server")
const webpack = require("webpack")
const config = require("./webpack.config")

const compiler = webpack(config)

const server1 = new WebpackDevServer(compiler.compilers[0], {
    contentBase: __dirname,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: false,
    compress: true,
})

const server2 = new WebpackDevServer(compiler.compilers[1], {
    contentBase: __dirname,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: false,
    compress: true,
})

server1.listen(3000, "localhost", function() {})
server2.listen(5000, "localhost", function() {})
```

You create a `webpack-dev-server` instance for each `compiler`.

Other way you can do this is to write multiple scripts in your package.json like this:

```
{
   "scripts":{
       "serve1": "webpack-dev-server --content-base <file/directory/url/port> --port 3000",
       "serve2": "webpack-dev-server --content-base <file/directory/url/port> --port 5000"
   }
}
```

and then run both scripts using `npm-run-all`,

```
npm-run-all serve1 serve2
```

Answer (score 1):

Two node instance in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --watch --mode=development --config-name='survey' & NODE_ENV=dev node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --watch --mode=development --config-name='account'",
    "build": "node ./node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist && node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli --mode=production"
  },
```

This is two different config. In every config have different dev config

```
const account = require("./account.config");
const survey = require("./survey.config");
module.exports = [account, survey];
```